# Change field from date to datetime

Tags: python, django, date, datetime, migration

I need to change a models field from `DateField`to `DateTimeField`. The migrations generated by `./manage.py makemigrations` only change the column type from date to datetime, but they don't migrate existing data.

For example when I change the following model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    time = models.DateField()
```

to

```
class Post(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField()
```

the values of the time column will still be dates (like `2016-12-21`) in the database. As a result, `post.time` will be `None` for every Post.

Instead, each object like `datetime.date(2016, 12, 21)` should become `datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 21, 0, 0)` automatically. What's the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Data Migrations documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)

your migration could be:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from datetime import datetime

from django.db import migrations, models

def update_time(apps, schema_editor):
    Post = apps.get_model("yourappname", "Post")
    for post in Post.objects.all():
        post.time = datetime.combine(post.time, datetime.min.time())
        post.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('yourappname', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(update_time),
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new column that is a DateTimeField. Run `./manage.py makemigrations`
2. Run `./manage.py migrate`
3. Create a manual migration script to pull the dates from the DateField and update the row's DateTimeField.
4. Remove the DateField. Run `./manage.py makemigrations`
5. Run `./manage.py migrate`, this will run #3 migration file and then #4 to remove the DateField.